# How to get Inifinite Values for textbox

Tags: javascript

how do I change that the user is able to key in the value from 0- infinite?
Because it only allows the user to key in from 0-9 at this moment.

```js
function validate() {
  var values = document.getElementById("digit").value;

  if (/^[0-9]$/.test(values) == false) {
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "This is not a number, number must be greater or equal to zero";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Your regex is allowing one character in the `[0-9]` set, you need to allow any number of digits if you want to use this sort of regex matching.

Comment: why not using number > 0

Comment: @DBS how do I do that?

Comment: If you add the `*` character after your set, it will match between 0-unlimited characters in that set `[0-9]*`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof` and the urnary operator `+` to check if its an number and greater equal then 0

```js
function validate() {
  var value = document.getElementById("digit").value;

  if (!(!isNaN(+value) && value >= 0)) {
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "This is not a number, number must be greater or equal to zero";
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "";
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="validate()" value="" id="digit" />

<p id="numbers"></p>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `typeof +value`? As far as I can tell that will return "number" regardless of the value of `value`.

Comment: @DBS i know it will return `NaN` but i didnt know that `typeof NaN` is also number.

Comment: @lfraruki how do I want to display my error message if lets I have create var values and var values1. values containing a lower number and values containing a higher number. How can I display the error message saying higher number is lower then smaller number

Answer (score 0):

Your Regular expression is looking for one and only one digit between the start and end of the string.

Try `/^[0-9]$+/`.
The `+` means 'At least one, up to an infinity of' whatever it's stuck too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the native method [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) to check if the last character is a number. If not, slice it.

```js
function validate(el) {
  var lastChar = Number(el.value.slice(-1));
  if (!Number.isInteger(lastChar)) {
    el.value = el.value.substring(0, el.value.length - 1);
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="validate(this)">
```